# Inline an input and a div within a table cell

Tags: html, css

does anyone know how to Inline an input and a div within a table cell?
this is the code:

```
<td>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" data-tier-id="1" class="form-control notes" value="2.829%">
    <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please add: `.form-control, .input-group-addon { display: inline-block; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple.  Just add the following CSS code:

```css
.form-control,.input-group-addon {
  display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<td>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" data-tier-id="1" class="form-control notes" value="2.829%">
    <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
</div>
</td>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding a title for the `input`, in which case I would recommend using a `<label>` tag instead of `<div>`.

```
<td>
<div class="input-group">
    <label><input type="text" data-tier-id="1" class="form-control notes" value="2.829%">%</label>
</div>
</td>
```

Otherwise..

CSS:

```
.form-control notes, .input-group-addon {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" data-tier-id="1" class="form-control notes" value="2.829%">
    <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
</div>
</td>
```